# Maui class library can't compile Android (No Android nameapace)

Tags: class-library, maui

I'm trying to create a Maui class library that has platform dependent sections.
In the class library's platform section for Android I've added code for Android, but when I compile it tells me that it can't find the Android namespace. I've check the Nuget packages against the main program that does compile Android and there the same. I've unloaded both the main project and the class library and check the project code against each other and there almost identical. The only difference that I can find between the main project that does compile Android is that the class library has an extra net6.0 dependency.

Comment: So you compared contents in `.csproj`s? If those are same, then the following should be consistent - but I'll mention anyway:  Solution Explorer / **yourproject / properties** / Target frameworks, does the list include `net6.0-android`? / Build / General / Conditional compilation symbols show entry for `Debug & net6.0-android`?

Comment: Yes it does. I've tried to create the class library several times even as a stand alone solution (not part of the main program) and I keep getting the same results. I just will not accept Xamarin Android code. Keeps telling me that there's no Android namespace.

Comment: I found wrapping using statements and platform-specific code in compiler directives fixed this problem:
```#if ANDROID\n
using Android.Content;\n
using MobileApp.Platforms.Android;\n
#endif```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a ".NET MAUI Class Library (Preview)" in VS 2022 Preview 3. Indeed, something is wrong - especially with Intellisense. I did not find a way to suppress certain Intellisense errors, but I did succeed in getting it to build.

NOTE: I confirmed that most of the issues do not interfere with Building the project. Indeed, its possible that the problem is ONLY with Intellisense; I didn't rigorously determine whether Build always worked.

**1) OPTIONAL:** In `.csproj`, REMOVE `.net6.0;` from start of `<TargetFrameworks>`. BUT DON'T remove, if you are making a library that doesn't contain platform-specific code.
EXPLANATION: This only affects Intellisense; can Build without doing this.
Normally this is wanted in a .net6 class library, but until VS Intellisense correctly handles Maui Class Libraries, with their platform-specific code, this tends to cause extra Intellisense complaints. If you do (4) for all platform-specific files, you can probably leave `.net6.0;` in, without extra Intellisense errors.

**2)** Above any source file, is a dropdown that says `YourLibName (net6.0-xxx)`. When working on Android code, pick `YourLibName (net6.0-android)`.
EXPLANATION: This only affects Intellisense; can Build without doing this.

**3)** In your code, use `global::Android` instead of `Android`.
EXPLANATION: Intellisense seems to be confused about the context it is in. `global::` ensures that it is looking for a "top-level" namespace.

**4)** In a class library, Intellisense isn't recognizing platform folders - wrap all code in appropriate `#if ANDROID`, `#if IOS`, etc.
EXPLANATION: This only affects Intellisense; can Build without doing this.
This removes errors for a class that is defined differently in multiple platforms; e.g `class PlatformClass1`.

**5)** `using Android;`, `using Android.App`, etc - do work (in platform-specific folder) when "Build" - even if Intellisense complains.

Comment: I eventually managed to get it to compile, don't know how. I was just about to give up and was sitting in front of the computer when all of a sudden Visual Studio's error output screen changed and the errors disappeared. Now it will compile about 50% of the time. When it stops compiling I close Visual Studio, reopen it, clean the project and then rebuild. But this also only work about 50% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -- I was determined not to believe @ToolmakerSteve's response but I'm afraid he's correct.  Especially #4 of his post about wrapping all platform specific content with

```
#if ANDROID
#endif
```

Also add it to your interfaces that reference platform specific namespaces.

Here's a link to a Microsoft page regarding this:
[invoke platform specific code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code)

Comment: I ended up taking a different tack. I created a global class library with a lot of static pluggable Func<> and Action<> callbacks. When the Android/IOS boots up it plugs these callbacks with the platform specific code. The main code then uses the callback in the global class library..