# .NET Maui Project Template Errors - The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, maui

I'm trying to start a new .net Maui project. I have added no code whatsoever to the starting project template.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit)
Preview Version 17.2.0 Preview 5.0
.NET Framework 4.7.2

Steps to reproduce:

1. Choose New Project, select .NET Maui App (Preview)
2. Name the project, click Create.
3. Open the file Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs

As soon as this file is opened 15 errors show up starting with "The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found." Although the project will successfully build, these errors never disappear. When real errors occur during a build, this makes it very difficult to continue.

I have tried cleaning the project with no luck.

Comment: **1)** If you successfully build, close that source window, close VS, reopen solution - do they reappear? **2)** A similar problem was seen in Maui `Class Library` - perhaps it is now also a problem for regular Maui project. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019029/199364) for partial work-around that might help you. **3)** Note: The Errors pane has a dropdown that can be set to `"Build Only"` (rather than "Build + Intellisense"), if your Build is failing and you only want to see those.

Comment: I found wrapping Android-specific using statements and code that sit in files outside of /Platforms/Android in a preprocessor directive fixed this problem for me: 
```#if ANDROID\n using Android.Content;\n using MobileApp.Platforms.Android;\n #endif```

Comment: @Netricity, thank you, you saved me from going insane lol!

Comment: @Netricity Thanks a bunch! Just like *Chris Parker* you also saved me from getting booked into a mental healthcare facility.

Comment: Could also move the files so that they are under /Platforms/Android